# Finite spanning set of the subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

First first of all, I apologize if my question is repeated.

In my text, there was a question that I was supposed to find the distinct finite spanning set for the following subspace, and I tried to transform it from parametric form, but I still don’t understand the general process to find the spanning set here.

$A = \{(x,y,z,w) \in \mathbb R^4 | x-y+z-w = 0\}$.

I do understand the way to write one parameter based on others but since here we got 4 parameters I’m not sure if that works. Could you please give me some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routine is generally given by

[image]

But in this case your "system" has only one equation, $x-y+z-w=0$, which means that you will have 3 degrees of freedom (4 variables total, 1 of them is the pivot).

So, choosing $x$ as the pivot, then $x=y-z+w$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\vec{x} = (x,y,z,w)\in A &\Longleftrightarrow \vec{x} = (y-z+w,y,z,w) \\
&\Longleftrightarrow \vec{x}= (y,y,0,0)+ (-z,0,z,0) + (w,0,0,w) \\
& \Longleftrightarrow \vec{x} = y(1,1,0,0) + z(-1,0,1,0) + w(1,0,0,1) \\
& \Longleftrightarrow \vec{x} \in span((1,1,0,0),\ (-1,0,1,0),\ (1,0,0,1) )
\end{align*}

Thus, $A = span((1,1,0,0),\ (-1,0,1,0),\ (1,0,0,1) )$

PS. In this case you can freely choose your pivot, so you can find other sets of generators for the same subspace.